# Encode a string by number of letters seen

Tags: python

For example,

- input 'aaabbabccd'
- output '4a3b2c1d'

i tried i am getting like '3a2b1a1b2c1d' but my expectation is '4a3b2c1d'

my code is like this

```py
def encode_string(s):
    if not s:
        return ""

    encode string = ""
    count = 1

    for i in range(1, len(s)):
        if s[i] == s[i - 1]:
            count += 1
        else:
            encoded_string += str(count) + s[i - 1]
            count = 1

    encoded_string += str(count) + s[-1]

    return encoded_string

input_string = 'aaabbabccd'
encoded_output = encode_string(input_string)
print(encoded_output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of occurrences of a character in a string with the `.count()` method. If you keep track of the characters you already counted, you can achieve the desired results:

```
def encode_string(s):
    encoded_string = ""

    for char in s:
        if char not in encoded_string:
            num = s.count(char)
            encoded_string += str(num) + char

    return encoded_string

input_string = 'aaabbabccd'
output_string = encode_string(input_string)
print(output_string)
```

Comment: It would be more effecient to use a dictionary rather than a string

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary constructor to get distinct letters in the same order as the input.  Then count each letter with the string's count() method and assemble the result using join.

```
encoded_output = "".join(f"{input_string.count(c)}{c}" 
                         for c in dict.fromkeys(input_string))

print(encoded_output) # 4a3b2c1d
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to produce the required output of 4a3b2c1d

Comment: Indeed, I misread the question.  Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Counter class from the *collections* module as follows:

```
from collections import Counter

myString = 'aaabbabccd'

print(''.join(f'{v}{k}' for k, v in Counter(myString).items()))
```

**Output:**

```
4a3b2c1d
```

**Optionally:**

If you don't want to import Counter you could implement your own:

```
def counter(s):
    d = {}
    for c in s:
        d[c] = d.get(c, 0) + 1
    return d

myString = 'aaabbabccd'

print(''.join(f'{v}{k}' for k, v in counter(myString).items()))
```